# How to dynamically change the value of a variable from an imported JS file to Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

There is an app file. The js in which YmapsComponent.vue is declared and imported ymaps.js.

```
import '../js/ymaps.js';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
const app = createApp({});
import YmapsComponent from './components/YmapsComponent.vue';
app.component('ymaps-component', YmapsComponent) ;
app.mount('#app');
```

In ymaps.js the route is being built at the specified points using the API. In this file, the length variable is specified globally and then exported to YmapsComponent.vue.

```
var length;
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Стоимость за километр.
    var DELIVERY_TARIFF = 30,
    // Минимальная стоимость.
        MINIMUM_COST = 500,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.7549792211111,37.61615189062498],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: []
        }),
    // Создадим панель маршрутизации.
        routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
            options: {
                maxWidth: '500px',
                minWidth: '200px',
            }
        }),
        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
            options: {
                size: 'small',
                float: 'none',
                position: {
                    bottom: 145,
                    right: 10
                }
            }
        });
    // Пользователь сможет построить только автомобильный маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.options.set({
        types: {auto: true}
    });

    myMap.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);

    // Получим ссылку на маршрут.
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function (route) {

        // Зададим максимально допустимое число маршрутов, возвращаемых мультимаршрутизатором.
        route.model.setParams({results: 1}, true);

        // Повесим обработчик на событие построения маршрута.
        route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function () {

            var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
            if (activeRoute) {
                // Получим протяженность маршрута.
                length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance")
                var duration = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("duration"),
                // Вычислим стоимость доставки.
                    price = calculate(Math.round(length.value / 1000)),
                // Создадим макет содержимого балуна маршрута.
                    balloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                        '<span>Расстояние: ' + length.text + '.</span><br/>' +
                        // '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic">Стоимость доставки: ' + price + ' р.</span>' +
                        '<span>Время в пути: ' + duration.text + '</span>');
                        
                // Внешний вид маршрута
                route.options.set({
                    // Цвет метки начальной точки.
                    // wayPointStartIconFillColor: "#B3B3B3",
                    // Цвет метки конечной точки.
                    // wayPointFinishIconFillColor: "red",     
                    // Внешний вид линий.
                    routeActiveStrokeColor: "#ff4f1e"
                });

                // Зададим этот макет для содержимого балуна.
                route.options.set('routeBalloonContentLayout', balloonContentLayout);


                // Откроем балун.
                activeRoute.balloon.open();
            }
        });

    });
    // Функция, вычисляющая стоимость доставки.
    function calculate(routeLength) {
        return Math.max(routeLength * DELIVERY_TARIFF, MINIMUM_COST);
    }
}
export {length}
```

The length value is output in YmapsComponent.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1 class="card-header color-red">{{  messages }}</h1>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Length  {{ delivery }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { length } from '../ymaps';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                messages:  "test",
                deliveryLength: 0,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            delivery() {
                if (length) {
                    this.deliveryLength = length.text;
                    return this.deliveryLength;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**The problem is that the deliveryLength value only changes when something is changed in the Vue file**. For example, [it selects points,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWOka.png) the map idles the route, but its length is not displayed in the component, and if, for example, [you change the value of messages,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpsO2.png) then the   [length will change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flXlD.png).

I searched for information on the Internet, tried different ways, but could not solve the problem

Comment: Put length as global (`window._length = length.text`), then use it as computed in vue: `computed(() => window._length)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering with the length variable not updating in your YmapsComponent.vue is due to the fact that Vue cannot reactively update data properties with values imported from an external file the way you're trying to do. When Vue's reactivity system is initialized, it tracks properties on the data object of a component. Since length is not a reactive data property within the Vue component, changes to it won't be tracked or cause updates in the DOM.

To make this work, you should emit an event from your ymaps.js file when the length changes and listen to this event in your Vue component to update deliveryLength. Here's a conceptual example of how you can achieve this:

In ymaps.js, emit a custom event when the length changes:

```js
// Assuming we have access to a Vue app instance or a way to emit global events
function updateLength(newLength) {
  length = newLength;
  // Emit a global event with the new length value
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('length-updated', { detail: length }));
}
```

In YmapsComponent.vue, listen for the event and update deliveryLength accordingly:

```html
<template>
  <!-- Your template -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            messages: "test",
            deliveryLength: 0,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // Listen for the 'length-updated' event
        window.addEventListener('length-updated', this.updateDeliveryLength);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        // Clean up the event listener when the component is destroyed
        window.removeEventListener('length-updated', this.updateDeliveryLength);
    },
    methods: {
        updateDeliveryLength(event) {
            // Update the deliveryLength with the new length value
            this.deliveryLength = event.detail.text;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        delivery() {
            return this.deliveryLength || 0;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

In this example, we're using the browser's window.dispatchEvent and window.addEventListener to communicate between the external JS file and the Vue component. This is a vanilla JS approach to event handling; you could also use Vue's own event system if you're working within a single Vue application instance.

Comment: As you've already been made aware on other answers you've deleted, use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic.